# Formal proof of $P\to Q, (P\to Q)\to (T\to S), \neg Q, P\lor T\vdash S$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, solution-verification, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

This is an example exam question that I'm wondering if I did right? We weren't given an answer key, so I'm checking to make sure I'm comprehending the material and if my answer is correct?

Premises: P $\Rightarrow$ Q, (P $\Rightarrow$ Q) $\Rightarrow$ (T $\Rightarrow$ S), $\lnot$Q, P $\lor$ T

Conclusion: S

My answer:

1. P $\Rightarrow$ Q: Given
2. (P $\Rightarrow$ Q) $\Rightarrow$ (T $\Rightarrow$ S): Given
3. $\lnot$Q: Given
4. P $\lor$ T: Given
5. T $\Rightarrow$ S: Modus Ponens 1 and 2
6. $\lnot$P: Modus Tollens 1 and 3
7. T: Disjunctive Syllogism 4 and 6
8. S: Modus Ponens 5 and 7

Comment: It's correct.${}$

Comment: Yep, looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof seems fine. This is a community wiki post so that the question is not marked as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

This proof is correct according to this [proof checker](http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/):

[image]

Modus ponens is conditional elimination on lines 5 and 8.